# How to use imported function inside page.evaluate in Puppeteer with Jest?

Tags: typescript, import, module, jestjs, puppeteer

I have a TypeScript project that uses Jest for unit tests and have just added Puppeteer to the mix with the intention to run some tests on the client. It works fine, unless I try use imported functions inside `page.evaluate`.

For example, I have the following in `HdpiCanvas.test.ts`:

```
import { createHdpiCanvas } from "./HdpiCanvas";

test("createHdpiCanvas", async () => {
    await page.setViewport({ width: 800, height: 600, deviceScaleFactor: 2 });
    let size = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const canvas = createHdpiCanvas(); // document.createElement('canvas');
        return [canvas.width, canvas.height];
    });
    console.log(size); // [600, 300] for HDPI canvas and [ 300, 150 ] for a regular one
});
```

With the commented out `document.createElement('canvas')` the test runs just fine and logs `[ 300, 150 ]`. But with the `createHdpiCanvas()` the following error is thrown by the `page.evaluate` function:

```
Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: HdpiCanvas_1 is not defined
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:2:24
```

The actual `createHdpiCanvas` inside `HdpiCanvas.ts` is defined as follows:

```
export function createHdpiCanvas(width = 300, height = 150): HTMLCanvasElement {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    applyHdpiOverrides(canvas);
    return canvas;
}
```

and itself depends on other functions defined in `HdpiCanvas.ts`, like `applyHdpiOverrides`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution suggested by Meni Roytenburd is correct. If you don't like the fact that every function needs to be exposed to the browser separately, the only idea that comes to mind is transpiling your project to a single JavaScript file first and then injecting it as a `<script>` tag — just like you would in real life.

The first step would be to generate a single JavaScript file with your bundle. Sometimes this can be accomplished with the TypeScript compiler alone, but a tool like Webpack can be used, too.

Once it's done, you can move your bundle to the client from within Puppeteer:

```
await page.addScriptTag({ path: 'path/to/the/bundle' });
```

Keep in mind this still may expose your functions to the global scope, hence accessing them via `window`.

```
  let size = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const canvas = window.createHdpiCanvas();
      return [canvas.width, canvas.height];
  });

  console.log(size); // [ 300, 150 ]
```

Another downside to this approach to having to deal with the warnings generated by TypeScript — at this point it doesn't know that `createHdpiCanvas` exists on `window`, so accessing `window.createHdpiCanvas` will cause an error.

Comment: Although this might work, but just like you said there are some downsides, I wonder why this is not well supported given such a common need among developers? Also I wonder, if `page` changes (i.e. navigation happens), we need to inject the script file again and again, right? This doesn't look good IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

you can do like this before you invoke the `evaluate` function :

```
await page.exposeFunction("applyHdpiOverrides",applyHdpiOverrides);
await page.exposeFunction("createHdpiCanvas",createHdpiCanvas);
```

and now your window will recognize these functions

Comment: I have tried that and don't want to go this route for several reasons: it's tedious that you have to expose them one by one, the functions are exposed on the page's `window` object, and I still ran into errors with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

As you may have figured it out already, the reason why `page.evaluate` fails is because the function is evaluated in a different context and the current scope (where `createHdpiCanvas` is available outside of the function) is lost.

I’m not familiar with pupeteer at all but by looking at the documentation for that function, there may be something you can try. It’s not pretty but perhaps it’s worth trying:

You could pass `createHdpiCanvas` as a parameter, however a function is not serialisable so you would have to do it yourself:

```
page.evaluate((createHdpiCanvasCode) => {
  const createHdpiCanvas = new Function(`return ${createHdpiCanvasCode}`)();
  const canvas = createHdpiCanvas();
  return [canvas.width, canvas.height];
}, createHdpiCanvas.toString());
```

However, you would have to inject your dependencies in the same way.